# Recompile PHP with ZTS enabled on Ubuntu

Tags: php, pthreads, pecl

I am trying to install pthreads by using

```
pecl install pthreads
```

But I got this error during the installation

```
configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
```

I have searched for this error. It seems that I have to install a new version of PHP with ZTS enabled. Is there any simpler ways to recompile with ZTS enabled instead of reinstalling PHP?

Answer (score 11):

Here is the quoted answer from a Digital Ocean community [comment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-zts-support-on-ubuntu-14-04):

> ZTS support is a configure time option and can not be enabled at run
>   time. You'll need to build php yourself with the
>   `--enable-maintainer-zts` flag in order to enable it.
>
> One way to do this is to modify the existing package and rebuild it.
>   First we'll need to install and download a few things:
>
> Install the build dependencies:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get build-dep php5
> ```
>
> Install the developer tools:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install devscripts
> ```
>
> Download the source:
>
> ```
> apt-get source php5
> ```
>
> Now enter the source directory and edit the debian/rules file:
>
> ```
> cd php5-5.5.9+dfsg/    # The version will be different depending on the Ubuntu release
> nano debian/rules
> ```
>
> Find the section starting with
>   `COMMON_CONFIG=--build=$(DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE) \` and add the following
>   configure flags:
>
> ```
>         --enable-maintainer-zts \
>         --enable-pthreads \
> ```
>
> Then we want to bump the version number for the package, so that it is
>   higher than the version of PHP in the repository. Run `dch -i` and
>   create a new changelog entry:
>
> ```
> php5 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5+zts1) trusty; urgency=medium
>
>   * Rebuild with ZTS support.
>
>  -- You <doesnt@matter.com>  Mon, 10 Nov 2014 13:14:32 -0500
> ```
>
> Now the package can be built using the command:
>
> ```
> DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck debuild
> ```
>
> This will take quite awhile and will also require some memory. If
>   you're on a 512mb server, you'll probably need to add some swap.
>
> It will produce a number of packages in the parent directory:
>
> ```
> cd ..
> ls *deb
> ```
>
> You can now install the individual packages with `sudo dpkg -i
>   pakage_name.deb` or all of them with `sudo dpkg -i *deb`

Comment: Thanks for this. It has been very helpful. To anyone reading this in the future, this method works for php 7 as well. Just make sure you run sudo apt-get install build-deps php7.0

Comment: It actually does't, Native Coder.
This is the exit of the command:
`sudo apt-get build-dep php7.0
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
E: Impossível encontrar um pacote fonte para php7.0`

Comment: @ViniciusDias what does your error message mean in English? I have issues with rebuilding PHP too.

Comment: It means `Reading package lists... Done E: Impossible to find a source package for php7.0`